# Navigation Drawer icon is not showing and OnNavigationItemSelectedListener is not working on click

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, navigation-drawer

**I am using a bottom navigation with tab fragment in my Launcher Activity.**
**Now I want to use Navigation Drawer. Navigation drawer works but no icon and no response while onclick**

My LauncherActivity holds the BottomNavigationView and BottomNavigationView holds fragments. I added the code for Navigation Drawer on my LauncherActivity. But there is no icon showing. Navigation Drawer works on sliding bit onclick event is not working on Navigation Drawer

All codes are here. Please help

**LauncherActivity.java**

```
package com.cornicore.dream11statistics;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class LauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Tab1.OnFragmentInteractionListener,Tab2.OnFragmentInteractionListener,Tab3.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);


        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.nav_drawer_home);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigationViewHome);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                int id = item.getItemId();

                if (id == R.id.nav_home_news){
                    Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this,"News",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (id == R.id.nav_home_schedule){
                    Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this,"Schedule",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (id == R.id.nav_home_upcoming_series){
                    Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this,"Series",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (id == R.id.nav_home_ranking){
                    Toast.makeText(LauncherActivity.this,"Ranking",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if (id == R.id.nav_home_point_table){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(LauncherActivity.this,KKRActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

                return false;
            }
        });


//Ads

        prepareAd();

        ScheduledExecutorService schedule = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        schedule.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                            interstitialAd.show();
                        }

                        prepareAd();
                    }
                });
            }
        },3,300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Ads


// Bottom Navigation Start

                BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListner);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new HomeFragment()).commit();

// Bottom Navigation

    }


// Bottom Navigation Start
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListner = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    android.support.v4.app.Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                    switch(item.getItemId()){
                        case R.id.nav_home:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_pointtable:
                            selectedFragment = new PointTableFragment();
                            break;

                        case R.id.nav_tricks:
                            selectedFragment = new TricksFragment();
                            break;
                    }


                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,selectedFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            };

    @Override
    public void OnNavFragmentInteractionListener(Uri uri) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }




    public void prepareAd(){

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-2696458474841326/2346748005");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.menuShare){

            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "Hey,Install this App and Play Dream 11 with proper statistics...Rate and Share https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cornicore.dream11statistics";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, " ");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));

        }

        if (id == R.id.menuRateUs){

    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.cornicore.dream11statistics")));


        }

        if (id == R.id.menuFeedback){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this,FeedbackActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**activity_launcher.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_home"
    tools:context=".LauncherActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationViewHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu_home"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation" />


        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">


        </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>


    </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**navigation_menu_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home_news"
        android:title="News"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list_black_24dp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home_schedule"
        android:title="Schedule"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list_black_24dp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home_upcoming_series"
        android:title="Upcoming Series"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list_black_24dp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home_ranking"
        android:title="Ranking"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list_black_24dp" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_home_point_table"
        android:title="Point Table"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_view_list_black_24dp" />

</menu>
```

**navigation_header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/share_background_gradient">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_logo" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make the activity implement the interface instead of creating an object instance

Comment: You can also generate a fully functioning activity via templates. Why complicate yourself creating everything by hand?

Comment: Assuming you have an `ActionBar` in `LauncherActivity`, you need to call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` to show the toggle icon. And the `<NavigationView>` needs to be listed after the `<RelativeLayout>` to get it to receive clicks.

Comment: Are you using 28.0.0-alpha1? I have the same problem, if I change to 27.1.1 support library, it works fine.